# iptables drop hex-string tcp synack

Tags: iptables

I'm not sure can drop packet syn ack flood with hex string match, can someone help me and give me clue how to do this?

```
 17:03:10.274551 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 89, id 6656, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
        94.73.253.181.57383 > 104.194.219.130.6410: Flags [.], cksum 0x100e (correct), seq 0, ack 1, win 131, options [nop,nop,TS val 125819447 ecr 1772061023], length 0
            0x0000:  0016 3e40 883e 8071 1fe7 0981 0800 4500
            0x0010:  0034 1a00 4000 5906 6780 5e49 fdb5 68c2
            0x0020:  db82 e027 190a 0000 0000 0000 0001 8010
            0x0030:  0083 100e 0000 0101 080a 077f da37 699f
            0x0040:  815f
    17:03:10.274812 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 88, id 5731, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
        11.200.80.242.55382 > 104.194.219.130.28238: Flags [.], cksum 0xf466 (correct), seq 0, ack 1, win 16616, options [nop,nop,TS val 125819432 ecr 247032168], length 0
            0x0000:  0016 3e40 883e 8071 1fe7 0981 0800 4500
            0x0010:  0034 1663 4000 5806 6b62 0bc8 50f2 68c2
            0x0020:  db82 d856 6e4e 0000 0000 0000 0001 8010
            0x0030:  40e8 f466 0000 0101 080a 077f da28 0eb9
            0x0040:  6968
    17:03:10.274929 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 90, id 46068, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
        92.227.88.168.42173 > 104.194.219.130.49430: Flags [.], cksum 0x08c2 (correct), seq 0, ack 1, win 16800, options [nop,nop,TS val 125819447 ecr 1772061023], length 0
            0x0000:  0016 3e40 883e 8071 1fe7 0981 0800 4500
            0x0010:  0034 b3f4 4000 5a06 72ff 5ce3 58a8 68c2
            0x0020:  db82 a4bd c116 0000 0000 0000 0001 8010
            0x0030:  41a0 08c2 0000 0101 080a 077f da37 699f
            0x0040:  815f
    17:03:10.275142 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 87, id 20342, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
        21.253.248.223.61050 > 104.194.219.130.50090: Flags [.], cksum 0x16ae (correct), seq 0, ack 1, win 254, options [nop,nop,TS val 125819432 ecr 247032168], length 0
            0x0000:  0016 3e40 883e 8071 1fe7 0981 0800 4500
            0x0010:  0034 4f76 4000 5706 812c 15fd f8df 68c2
            0x0020:  db82 ee7a c3aa 0000 0000 0000 0001 8010
            0x0030:  00fe 16ae 0000 0101 080a 077f da28 0eb9
            0x0040:  6968
```

Answer (score 0):

What pattern are you trying to match?  Attacks can change up most of the fields in a header on each request, so blocking this from a string match will not be very effective and will consume more CPU.

Please consider instead using some of the common methods of blocking packets that don't arrive in the correct order.  [Here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-iptables-10-how-to-block-common-attack.html) are a few examples.

Here are a few things you could put in the "raw" table in iptables to block packets with invalid sequences:

```
iptables -t raw -I PREROUTING -p tcp --tcp-flags ALL NONE -j DROP
iptables -t raw -I PREROUTING -p tcp --tcp-flags ALL ALL -j DROP
iptables -t raw -I PREROUTING -p tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN FIN,SYN -j DROP
iptables -t raw -I PREROUTING -p tcp --tcp-flags SYN,RST SYN,RST -j DROP
iptables -t raw -I PREROUTING -p tcp --tcp-flags ALL FIN,PSH,URG -j DROP
iptables -t raw -I PREROUTING -p tcp --tcp-flags ALL FIN -j DROP
```

If this helps, then be sure to save it with iptables-save > /path/to/your/iptables config file.

Sometimes these tools also don't properly set the mss size and you can block those with:

```
iptables -t raw -I PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -m tcpmss ! --mss 536:65535 -j DROP
```

There are many other methods of blocking invalid and spoofed packets, but that would be an extensive write-up.  There are some articles on this site that go into more detail on each of the methods.

If there is something specific you would like to block using a hex-string match, let me know the sequence and I will try to help you with it.  I would advise against this unless you are certain that string will only match spoofed traffic.

Comment: can you make hex string u32 with simulation  seq 0, ack 1 syn for drop ? its possible or no